# Map and Filter mapped array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This a very simple question. I want to map and form an array given another array. then I would like to remove the duplicated values.

this is what I did:

```
let status = listHotels.map(hotel => {
  return hotel.status
})

const x = status.filter((v, i) => (
  status.indexOf(v) === i
));
```

It works. But I would like a solution that doesn't involve writing two blocks of code. I tried this:

```
let status = listHotels.map(hotel => {
  return hotel.status
}).filter((v, i) => (
  status.indexOf(v) === i
));
```

But it didnt work. It says

> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Does anyone know a workaround this?

Comment: status is not available inside the chained method

Comment: `status` will only be assigned once all chained methods have executed, with the result of the last chained method. So you attempting to access `status` inside a chained method before it has been assigned.

Comment: Why would you filter ? Because your statement `array.indexOf(v) === i` will always return true...

Comment: No it wont @ChrisR. It's a common way to remove duplicates from the array.

Answer (score 9):

status is still not defined when you call the `.filter` method.

change your code to:

```js
const listHotels = [{status:'s1'}, {status:'s1'}, {status:'s2'}]
let status = listHotels.map(hotel => {
  return hotel.status
}).filter((v, i, currentStatus) => (
  currentStatus.indexOf(v) === i
));
console.log(status);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), passing a function to compare statuses, and swapping filter/map around:

```js
const listHotels = [{status: 'bad'}, {status: 'good'}, {status: 'bad'}];

let status = listHotels.filter((v, i) =>
  listHotels.findIndex(v2 => v.status === v2.status) === i
).map(hotel => hotel.status);

console.log(status);
```

Answer (score 1):

*status* is not ready yet (`undefined`) to access inside the `filter()`. But in the first solution, *map()* returns and stores result in *status* which makes the variable available in the later statements.

You can pass the array itself as the third parameter to use in the `filter()`. You also do not need to use unnecessary *return* statement here:

```js
var listHotels = [{status:'a'}, {status:'b'}, {status:'a'}]

let status = listHotels.map(hotel => hotel.status)
                       .filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
console.log(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `let` and `const` I'm assuming you can also use ES6 [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const data = [{
  status: 'one',
  id: 1
}, {
  status: 'one',
  id: 2
}, {
  status: 'two',
  id: 3
}, {
  status: 'two',
  id: 4
}]

const uniqueStatus = [...new Set(data.map(({
  status
}) => status))]

console.log(uniqueStatus)
```

Passing the mapped array into `Set` will ensure uniqueness. You can destructure the Set back into an array.